# Anaconda Navigator not launching "Attribute error: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: anaconda, attributeerror, launch

I cannot launch Anaconda navigator outside of the first time it launches after installation.
uninstalling and reinstalling does not work.
commands such as **conda update anaconda-navigator** have not worked.
I am on windows 11.

Both launching from the anaconda prompt with **anaconda-navigator** or from desktop/search bar have been met with [an error message stating **Main error** 'bytes' object has no attribute 'get'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGEB5.png) error message on start up.
(I am sorry for not being able to write the text itself, but I cannot highlight and copy the text from the error message.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Perhaps this is your issue? https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11734

Answer (score 0):

met the same problem. I used the cmd `conda update anaconda-navigator` to try to fix it and find error msg, it showed some of my PATH is incorrect. I reeditted my System PATH according to the error msg.(I installed JAVA and modified some of my environment PATH before, and when I noticed my Added Paths were the reason for not working of Anaconda, I deleted the PATHs added for JAVA, now anaconda works well)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you did not check the option to add anaconda path when installing anaconda, because this option is not checked by default during installation. Try reinstalling and remember to check this option

Answer (score 0):

Open the anaconda prompt and type
conda --no-plugins update conda

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, I had the same issue and it turns out that I had to modify my PATH variable (in System Properties) to remove any entries with contained quotes.

In my specific case, I had to remove this from the PATH:
`'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\Hostx64\x86'`

After this, Anaconda Navigator and conda began working fine without a reboot.